# Import an activity from another project

Tags: android

As a total Android development beginner, I might be asking a stupid question here, but I thought I'd go for it anyway, since I have no clue about what to do.

I want to have a carousel kind of menu on my MainActivity for the app I'm trying to develop. I found this project after some searching : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

It's exactly the kind of carousel I want to put in my app, but I'm not sure whether I should import parts of the project containing the carousel (which is a demo of it, available to download) so I can use the same type of carousel in the MainActivity of my own app, or if it's a totally wrong way of thinking.

I think I've also figured that Android libraries are .jar files, and this carousel is a project, not a .jar, so I don't know if there is a way to get this kind of component inside my app.

I tried some dirty copying and adapting from one project into another, but I'm so new with even the basic structure of an Android app that I couldn't make anything out of it.

Any help or guidelines would be greatly appreciated. 
I'm planning to make a menu out of this kind of component, and couldn't find anything else closer to what I'm trying to do, for Android.

**EDIT :** I'm working on Eclipse

Comment: jar is different from library project. jar contains only .java files. Library project can have resource files (drawables,layouts,strings,etc..) as well. Its difficult to tell if this is a library project of not

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @erisco Eclipse, sorry I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

1. Stick the visual language of Android, Holo. Pushing clunky GUI that looks out of place is the last thing this platform needs.
2. You may mark a project as a library when you create it. You can then import it to another project with `Project Properties > Android > Add Library`. This point answers you question the most, I guess.
3. I strongly suggest understanding basic widgets and classes first. Don't go onto the deep waters. If you want flashy slidy things, take a look at `Fragment` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`classes. Plenty more examples that are free, to begin with. By using support library v4 and Android Sherlockbar you should get a better feel of the platform while keeping it up to day date and backward compatible.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, but the mockup for the school projet I'm working on has been made with such a carousel, it was not my decision in the first place. I also think this kind of components fits better with Apple's visual language but well, I'll have to deal with it.

Also, I tried to import the project after setting it to library as you said, but I've had plenty of errors then, so I kinda gave up on this option.

And for your third point, I agree, I'll get started with other activities in my app, I guess, and go back to this later.

Answer (score 0):

Download the project, then go File->Import->Android->Existing Code into Workspace and you will have that project in workspace.

If you want to add only activity then create your own one, File->New->Other->Android->Android Activity and then copy the code and check method setContentView() if it have the layout you need. If you have MainActivity activity with layout called activity_main (which is default) then just check if you have setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);.